# how to display set of maps in array format using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, set

I have added nested maps into a set and trying to display it in array format, how can i display it. Thanks in advance

I am trying to access in this way Array.from(success) but I am getting empty response

```
 Set {
     Map {
     'name' => 'Sana',
     'age' => '20',
     'image' => Map {
     'image.jpg' => '1560859330116' },
     'image' => 'N/A' },
     Map {
     'name' => 'Ria',
     'age' => '25',
     'image' => Map {
     'image.jpg' => '1560859330116' },
     'image' => 'N/A' }}
```

this is my input set

i want this to be in array format

Comment: Please edit the question to add clarification, don't put it in comments.

Comment: Show the input and the result you're trying to get.

Comment: This is not a **valid** JS input though...

Answer (score 0):

If you try to serialize a set or map into JSON, you will get an empty object, because they don't store property values like arrays and objects. If you are not using `JSON.stringify()` directly, then maybe you are sending data between a client and server or using some library that's serializing it. You need to convert, or just switch to using arrays and objects.

Is there any particular reason that you need a set of maps instead of an array of objects?

```js
const set = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(set));

const map = new Map([ ['a',1], ['b',2] ]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(map));

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

const obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

const arr_of_objs = [
   { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
   { 'c': 3, 'd': 3 }
];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr_of_objs));
```

Comment: You are right, I used array of objects instead of maps, Thanks Anyway

Comment: @VanishreeRavikumar no problem. I see you're new here, just a reminder to mark responses as answers, if they helped you.